# Creating 2 expanable rows drop down menu in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown in UITableView, which can expand rows inside another row.[image: Here's Sample] .

Can it be done by using nested UITableView?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Here are the steps:

1. Add a tableView with two(or more) **prototype cells**. The total number of types of cells should have UI configured in the ones in the tableView.
2. **Create classes** for each type of cell (don't forget to have different identifiers)
3. **Save** which **index** is exapnded
4. Use that in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

**When not expanded and clicked**

tableView.beginUpdates()

tableView.insertRows(at: customPath, with: .bottom)

tableView.endUpdates()

**When initially expanded**

tableView.beginUpdates()

tableView.deleteRows(at: customPath, with: .top)

tableView.endUpdates()